# Wakanda query/find 4D ObjectField.property.property

Tags: object, properties, find, wakanda

When from Wakanda I query or find on a 4D database table, object field, property.property value, the result is not what I expect. It is returning an entity with a non matching integer value, when the comparison operator is "===', or '=='.

I know that the Wakanda query is valid for the field name because it does not complain that the attribute is not found.

I know that the ObjectField.property.property value exists.

Please verify that 4D object field, properties can be queried/find from Wakanda, and that objectField.property.property can be queried/find.

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

The answer has been found. A bug report has been filed.